# angularjs - pass param from controller to service

Tags: angularjs-service

*controller.js*

From here to factory I want to pass a param:

```
getSurveyDataDrag.query(function(data){});
```

Like something:

```
getSurveyDataDrag.query(param: "1", function(){})
```

*service.js*

Want to get to inside factory(below) param value 1:

```
    .factory('getSurveyDataDrag', function($resource){  

    return $resource('/getSurveyData/:flag', {falg: '3'}, { 

    query: {method:'GET', params:{orderby1:''}, isArray:true}

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to angular too, and not being sure what exactly you are trying to do, I can at least offer this to hopefully help you along since no one else has yet :)

Instead of param: "1" in the following line:

```
getSurveyDataDrag.query(param: "1", function(){})
```

Try passing the parameter by name & value as an object literal, more like this:

```
getSurveyDataDrag.query({orderby: "whateverYouWantToOrderBy"}, function(response){
 //do what you wanna do here
});
```

Angular typically expects parameters to be passed in the form of an object in my experience, and you don't have to identify that they are parameters when you are just passing them through.

Now I'm not sure that syntax is right - I've had trouble finding info on .query myself. If that doesn't work, it could be that because you are overriding the natural angular query, you need to say getSurveyDataDrag.$query (note the $).

I hope that helps a bit!